# Bangla fonts not working in LibreOffice

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice, fonts, offline, ibus-avro

How can I install custom Fonts offline? I want to use Bangla fonts in LibreOffice 5

Some words are not showing correctly, for example (গ্রাম) is showing as (গ্ রাম)
.

*mentioned that I am using ibus-avro as Bangla typing software.*

date it is separated not in complex form..(শুক্ র)

How to solve this?

Comment: I am a beginner to Ubuntu. I used Windows. So I am finding if there is any way like drag and drop of fonts installation like Windows..

Comment: The [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org) is good reading for Ubuntu beginners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For Ubuntu 16.04 and above you must install the right language support

Go to **System Settings > Language Support > Install / Remove Languages**

[image]

and select **Bangla** (or any other languages). Then click on **Apply**

[image]

#### Mark Complex Text Layout settings in LibreOffice

1. Open LibreOffice Writer
2. Form the top menu select Tools > Option
3. Scroll down the left panel of the Options window to **Language Settings > Language**
4. Select **Complex Text Layout (CTL)** check mark, and select the language
       such as Bengali.

## Select Keyboard layout (if needed)

ibus is not supported any more (I think). If needed select an alternate keyboard layout:

1. Go to **Systems Settings > Keyboard > Text Entry**
2. Use the <kbd>+</kbd> icon at the bottom left to add a Bengali keyboard layout in addition to the default English one.

On my computer I have the following choices:

- Bangla
- Bangla (India)
- Bangla (India, Baisakhi)
- Bangla (India, Baisakhi inscript)
- Bangla (India, Bornona)
- Bangla (India, Probhat)
- Bangla (India, Uni, Gitanjali)

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: কাজ হয়েছে ধন্যবাদ (Thanks worked) on Libre office..

Comment: But my system still showing শুক্ র instead of শুক্র 

Comment: @user642711 Please ask another question with more details. What do you mean by system? Which app or on which screen?

Comment: .. date (On top of the screen, right corner)

Comment: @user642711 Please ask a new question about system font display. This is not related to LibreOffice. It should be fixed by enabling Bangla System language. I don't use Bangla as system language. May be someone else will be able to help.